# Any tips for improving at blindfold chess?

Tags: calculation, blindfold-chess

I've recently started training with some drills to improve at blindfold chess using the software chess eye. I also watched a video by IM Daniel Rensch where he went over certain blindfold drills used by the Soviet Union in their chess schools. Does anyone have any recommendations they could make about other methods to improve at this. I feel as though since I started my calculation has improved drastically and would like to continue the trend.